# Returning data from Flux store to React components with actions

Tags: reactjs, flux

I have been plugging away at this for around 3 days now and can find very few answers that relate to this.  This seems simple enough that I am certain I am missing something or approaching it the wrong way.  I have a React application using Flux.  My store and actions are working beautifully for updating and changing data, but I am stuck when it comes to retrieving the data from the store via actions and getting it into my component.

**Example Store**

```
class DiceStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.dice = [
            {name: 'purple',
             facts: PurpleDice.PurpleDice},
            {name: 'green',
             facts: GreenDice.GreenDice},
            {name: 'yellow',
            facts: YellowDice.YellowDice}, 
            {name: 'blue',
             facts: BlueDice.BlueDice},
            {name: 'black',
             facts: BlackDice.BlackDice},
            {name: 'red',
             facts: RedDice.RedDice},
            {name: 'white',
             facts: WhiteDice.WhiteDice}
        ];
    }

    getAllDice() {
        return this.dice;
    }

    handleActions(action) {
        switch(action.type) {   
            case "GET_ALL_DICE": {
                this.getAllDice();
                break;
            } 
            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Actions**

```
export function getAllDice() {
    diceDispatcher.dispatch({
        type: "GET_ALL_DICE"
    })
}
```

**Example Component**

```
export default class DiceHolder extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            allDice: DiceActions.getAllDice(), 
        }
    }
}
```

Everything I am seeing says that I should not be running functions in the store directly without utilizing an action.  However, when I try to use an action, the store does its thing correctly and can console log the data I need, but it only ever returns undefined in the component.  What do I need to rethink or do differently to get the actions actually returning static store data in my component?

Answer (score 1):

I see this one is quite old, but I will give it a try for future visitors.

You don't have to dispatch an action to *retrieve* data. The concept of unidirectional data flow is there for when you *change* (update/remove/add) data.

If you want to import data from your store to your component, simply call `DiceStore.getAllDice()` from your component.

This is what your current implementation is doing:

**Component:** -Hey dispatcher, inform the stores `GET_ALL_DICE`
**Dispatcher** -Every store around here, `GET_ALL_DICE`!
**Store:** -Ah, `GET_ALL_DICE` happened. I'll just run my `getAllDice()` method right here and don't tell anyone anything else.